# NVidia GT630M Surround Sound

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, surround-sound

I'm trying to work out if a particular computer (A Lenovo E530) can handle Surround Sound (through its HDMI cable) and if so how many channels It can provide.

I understand this laptop in question has an NVIDIA GT 630M chipset which provides HDMI, described as "HD Audio".  The specs for the system don't mention surround Sound (they do mention Dolby), but it seems that the HD Audio spec does allow for multiple channels, which has me confused.

Does anyone know if its possible to have more then 2 audio channels (ie stereo) for this computer ?   If so, am I correct in assuming that Surround output will only be available if the EDID of the device the HDMI plugs into advertises support for Surround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be "no", it is only possible to have stereo on this computer.